# Inconsistent currency symbol

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using the `StringFormat=\{0:C2\}` formatter to display currencies in my Silverlight 4 app, however it seems that for some controls (I'm mostly using `TextBlock` and `TextBox` controls) it picks the incorrect currency symbol (its using '$' where we use 'R') if the value is updated while the control is not currently displayed, if I update the value (of the property the control is bound to) while the control is on screen it corrects the currency symbol, has anyone experienced this before? Any suggestions on a fix?
It's really weird how some TextBox's have the correct currency symbol, and others in the same `Grid` don't

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that for providing correct currency string representation in TextBox better to use Converters.

Comment: Maybe... For me it is always better to handle such behaviors. We have met a lot of problems with localization during implementing such functionality.